# Mifare cards authentication

Tags: authentication, nfc

I have few questions about Mifare authentication:

1) Can you confirm me that the authentication between the reader and the tag is as follow: the reader send the correct key to the tag for the sector he wants to read/write.

2) So is there a problem If someone can sniff the data between the tag and the reader?

3) I know each sector has two keys (they can be used to write or read) and they may be different for each sector (and cards/tags?). How the reader know all the possible keys? Is there a sort of specific algorithm used for each vendor?